# need ideas for the minRow method

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have java worksheet, which uses arraylist. It is making a excel sheet. There are functions like total, count, getters and setters which i could solve it easily but I cannot seem to do the min method below, the requirements are as followed

The data looks something like this:

> ```
>        A(0)     B(1)    C(2)    D(3)    E(4)    F(5)
>     0   -       -       -       -       -       -
>     1   -       -       8.8     -       0.0     -0.1
>     2   -       -       -       -6.5    -       -
>     3   -       -       -       -       -       -
>     4   -       -       -       1.8     -1.4    -
>     5   -       -       -       -       -       -
>     6   0       1.9     -       -       -       -
>
>     ---------------------------
> ```

value of the first row for which there is a EntryData object
in the list data
return null if there is no data

```
public Integer minRow() {
    return null; //to be completed
}
```

The test data is here to check if the function works:

```
public void testMinRow() {
    assertNotNull(sheet.minRow());
    assertTrue(sheet.minRow()==1);
    assertNull(empty.minRow());
}
```

I got this far, but only the first test works here:

```
public Integer minRow() {
    int firstRow = 0;
    for(DataEntry item: data) {
        if(item.getRow() > firstRow)
            firstRow = item.getRow();
    }
    return firstRow; //to be completed
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow, try posting this in code review.

Comment: Do *not* post this on code review, this question is off-topic there. See [Be careful when recommending Code Review to askers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/253975/be-careful-when-recommending-code-review-to-askers) It's on-topic for SO but too broad as you haven't made any attempt and you're not showing an [mcve].

Comment: Oh, I forgot to paste my attempt.

Answer (score 0):

Why not using foreach to go throug the single lines, than save the value of the line and compare to the next value in this line and so on. at every compare, only save the smaller (min) value and at the end print this value out

Comment: I tried this, but this only works on the first test.

public Integer minRow() {
  int firstRow = 0;
  for(DataEntry item: data) {
   if(item.getRow() > firstRow)
    firstRow = item.getRow();
  }
  return firstRow;
 }